# Add legend to a ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a legend to a graph trough the next code in R.

```
limits<-ggplot(bands3, aes(x=H,y=C_min))+geom_line(color="red1")+
  geom_line(data=bands3, aes(x=H,y=C_max), color="red1")+
  geom_line(data=bands4[-1000,], aes(x=H,y=C_min),color="green1", size=0.5)+ 
  geom_line(data=bands4[-1000,], aes(x=H,y=C_max),color="green1", size=0.5)+
  geom_line(data=bands5, aes(x=H,y=C_min),color="purple1")+ 
  geom_line(data=bands5, aes(x=H,y=C_max),color="purple1")+
  geom_line(data=bands6[-1000,], aes(x=H,y=C_min),color="orange1")+ 
  geom_line(data=bands6[-1000,], aes(x=H,y=C_max),color="orange1")+
  geom_line(data=bands7[-1000,], aes(x=H,y=C_min),color="blue1")+ 
  geom_line(data=bands7[-1000,], aes(x=H,y=C_max),color="blue1")+
  scale_colour_manual(name="D",values=c(red1="#ED0603", green1="#0C9F10", 
purple1="#8A08E0",orange1="#ED6904",blue1="#210CDE"))+labs(x="X", y="Y")
```

Whose output is the following image

[Plot of some bands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U911t.png)

I want to use this object to plot some points later so I've refused in using grind.arrange to add the legend, and I've tried all possible solutions I've found here but there's no success. I'd like to know if someone could help me to solve this problem though unfotunally I can't share data. Thank you so much.

Edit: I also tried to do it using just one dataframe. This is the code I used

```
bands<-rbind(cbind("D"=rep(3,1000), bands3),cbind("D"=rep(4,999), 
bands4[-1000,]),cbind("D"=rep(5,1000),bands5),cbind("D"=rep(6,999), 
bands6[-1000,]), cbind("D"=rep(7,999),bands7[-1000,]))

bands$D<-as.factor(bands$D)

limits<-ggplot(bands, aes(x=H,y=C_min, group=D))+geom_line()+
geom_line(data=bands, aes(x=H,y=C_max,group=D))+ 
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#ED0603","#0C9F10",
                          "#8A08E0","#ED6904","#210CDE"))
```

but trough this code I just get the same plot without colors.

Comment: The proper & tidy `ggplot` way would be to have all data in one `data.frame` and then use the `colour` aesthetic to draw different curves; that automatically takes care of the legend. See my minimal example below.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate my comment above, here is a minimal example:

```
# Generate some data
df <- data.frame(
    x = 1:20,
    y1 = (1:20) * 0.5,
    y2 = (1:20) * 1,
    y3 = (1:20) * 1.5);

library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    gather(key, value, -x) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, value, colour = key)) + 
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I had completely ignored de colour argument into aes().